# AngularJS choosing between $rootScope and $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application where the frontend is build on AngularJS and backend is on laravel 5.1.

The user authentication is done by account controller via an API call:

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$auth,$location){

        $scope.authenticate = function(provider){
            $auth.authenticate(provider)
            .then(function() {
                  toastr.success('You have successfully signed in with ' + provider);
                  $location.path('/');
                })
                .catch(function(response) {
                  toastr.error(response.data.message);
                });
            };

});


angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('Account', function($http){
        return {
            getProfile: function(){
                 return $http.get('/api/me');
            }
        }
    });
```

Once authenticated, the function `getProfile` is called to populate user data into the view by controller:

```
myApp.controller('UserApiCtrl', function($scope,$auth,Account){
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.getProfile = function(){
        Account.getProfile()
            .then(function(response){

                $scope.user = response.data;
            })

            .catch(function(response){

            })
    };

    $scope.getProfile();
})
```

For the page to able render user data across all the different controller, should I assign user data with just `$scope` or assign it to `$rootScope` in app.js where user data will be available globally.

Comment: Using `$rootScope` to store "globals" is a major code smell.  You should use a service which is injected into each controller that requires the data. Since services are Singletons, every injection point will receive the same instance of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$cookies ("Provides read/write access to browser's cookies.")](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

```
  myApp.controller('UserApiCtrl', function($scope,$auth,Account,Auth,$cookies){
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.getProfile = function(){
            Account.getProfile()
                .then(function(response){
                    $cookies.putObject('user', response.data);
                })

                .catch(function(response){
                    if(response.status === 401)
                        $cookies.remove('user');
                })
        };

        $scope.getProfile();
    })
```

- Example service:

  ```
      myApp.factory('Auth', ['$rootScope', '$cookies', function($rootScope, $cookies) {
          $rootScope.user = $cookies.getObject('user') || {
              id: '',
              token: ''
          };
  ```

  ...

Answer (score 0):

I've used a controller on my body tag to provide access to more global stuff and then controllers in my individual views to do things that are more specific to the view.

```
<body ng-controller = "appController as app">
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

This just seems cleaner than using $rootScope to me.